# How to make userForm.$dirty true in angularjs ..?

Tags: angularjs

i want to change the form dirty value is true. 
   like   $scope.userForm.$dirty = true;  but it's not work.
plz help.

Comment: hi but my form is already dirty i want make its valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the $setDirty method that is exposed on the Angular [FormController here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController), That should do what you want. [Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gofwt9mp/); I can set the form to a dirty state either by typing something in the input boxes, or by clicking the button, through using the $setDirty method:

```
$scope.myForm.$setDirty();
```